# Language translation by PHP and ajax plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, language-translation

Hi every one I have been looking for a language translator in drop down with country icons, I dont know if I can use google or not ? but I found really good http://www.jqueryscript.net/text/jQuery-Plugin-To-Translate-Webpage-In-A-Given-Language-localizationTool.html

So I have decided to use this but I am having problem with the multiple languages.

Could any one help me with adding more languages into the drop down .

Here is the code

```
<script>
    $('#selectLanguageDropdown').localizationTool({
   'defaultLanguage' : 'en_GB',
   'ignoreUnmatchedSelectors': false,
    'showFlag' : true,
    'showLanguage': true,
     'showCountry': true,
    'labelTemplate': '{{country}} {{(language)}}',
    'languages' : {
     },
     'strings' : {},
     'onLanguageSelected' : function (/* je*/) { return true; }
      });

    </script>
```

I just need to add more languages to the drop down, I could not understand the documentation at the website please help/suggest me for language translator with icon drop down and which takes less space .

Thank you.

The main problem in this plugin is that i have to write the content in other language to convert the text. i want to translate the whole website, how can i write everything in all languages. can any one suggest me something like google translator in this design ???

Comment: Hi @Amani , in commentary they already explain you how to do it .                                           
The format here is <country code>_<language code>.
     * - list of country codes: http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Country-Codes.html

     * - list of language codes: http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Usual-Language-Codes.html#Usual-Language-Codes